# covariant type T in linked list

Tags: scala

I want to create a singly-linked list with `add` methods according the tutorial

[Learning Scala by building Scala - Lists](https://mauricio.github.io/2013/11/25/learning-scala-by-building-scala-lists.html)

Can you please resolve error?

```
Error:(6, 13) covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value element def add(element: T): MyLinkedList[T]
```

The error appeared when I add `+` to generic `[T]`, because method apply didn't work without `+`.

```
sealed trait MyLinkedList[+T] {
    def add(element: T): MyLinkedList[T]
}

object MyLinkedList {
  def apply[T](elements: T*): MyLinkedList[T] = {
    if (elements.isEmpty) {
      new Empty[Nothing]
    } else {
      Cons(elements.head, apply(elements.tail: _*))
    }
  }

  final case class Cons[T](element: T, rest: MyLinkedList[T]) extends MyLinkedList[T] {
        override def add(element: T): MyLinkedList[T] = ???
  }

  final case class Empty[T]() extends MyLinkedList[T] {
        override def add(element: T): MyLinkedList[T] = ???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error disappears if you change signature of `add`:

```
sealed trait MyLinkedList[+T] {
  def add[U >: T](element: U): MyLinkedList[T]
}
```

If you want to keep `MyLinkedList` invariant (without `+`) you can return `Empty[T]` rather than `Empty[Nothing]` in `apply`.